# Get the row height in the HeightForRowAt

Tags: ios, swift, uitableview

I have a `UITableViewController` with a custom `UITableViewCell`. Each cell has 2 labels. When the cell is selected it expands to a fixed value, I do it via `tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, heightForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> CGFloat` . I also have set the rowHeight = UITableViewAutomaticDimension , as some cells have to display multiple lines of text.
What I want to achieve is when a cell needs to be expanded I want to add 50 points to its current height. So here's the question, how can I get current height of the cell, when the `rowHeight = UITableViewAutomaticDimension` is set?

Here's my code for the fixed height for the selected state:

```
override func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, heightForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> CGFloat {
        if selectedIndexPath == indexPath {
            return selectedHeight
        }else{

        return tableView.estimatedRowHeight
        }
    }
```

**EDIT:** I also need to change it after that, by adding some variable to it.

Comment: Why do you need to add 50 (or dynamic amount) to automatically calculated height? If its some kinda padding can't you do it buy layout constraints on the storyboard and change the constant value (50 or any value) in cellForRowAtIndexPath method. If you wanna change the height of the selected cell then you can do set constants of your constraints on `override func setSelected(_ selected: Bool, animated: Bool)` method on your extended UITableViewCell class.

Comment: @RJE I want the cell, to be risezed to add some more content to it, when it is selected. I do it already.

Comment: Adding content is fine. but I suggest to do it with auto layouts instead of manually adding sizes. eg. put a clear UIview on the cell(let say as a line with zero height) in the storyboard with zero height and 999 priority. Then add subviews to it on `cellForRowAtIndexPath` (programmatically if you want) and set auto layouts for those subviews properly. It will resize the cell appropriately. When unselect remove all the subviews but keep the UIview with zero height constraint.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Building on HamzaLH's answer you might do something like this...

import UIKit

class TableViewController: UITableViewController {

```
var selectedRow: Int = 999 {
    didSet {
        tableView.beginUpdates()
        tableView.endUpdates()
    }
}


override func numberOfSections(in tableView: UITableView) -> Int {
    return 1
}

override func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
    return 5
}



override func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, heightForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> CGFloat {
    if indexPath.row == selectedRow {  //assign the selected row when touched
        let thisCell = tableView.cellForRow(at: indexPath)

        if let thisHeight = thisCell?.bounds.height {

            return thisHeight + 50

        }
    }
    return 60 //return a default value in case the cell height is not available
}

override func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, didSelectRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) {
    selectedRow = indexPath.row
}


override func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {

     let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "reuseIdentifier", for: indexPath)


    cell.detailTextLabel?.text = "test"


    return cell
}
```

}

I'm animating the expansion of the height with a didSet when a the selectedRow is altered.

Also, don't forget you may still need to connect your dataSource and delegate by dragging the outlets in Interface Builder to your View Controller in the storyboard.   After that you still need to add this to ViewDidLoad in your ViewController's swift file.   [image]

```
tableView.delegate = self
tableView.dataSource = self
```

I also have an Outlet declared for the tableView like below, and connected in Interface Builder storyboard.

```
@IBOutlet weak var tableView: UITableView!
```

[image]

Comment: Well, I've tried the same approach, but for some reason it doesn't work. It returns a right variable, but the cell itself does not change the height. What could be the issue?

Comment: Try adding this when you want the tableview height to refresh.
        tableView.beginUpdates()
        tableView.endUpdates()

Comment: Actually optional thisCell? is nil, when the function is called. However, as I've noticed, it gets called several times for some reason, and for the first time it is not nil

Comment: Okay, I've updated the code above...  A couple things..  1.) Make sure that you have connected your dataSource and delegate in the Storyboard in Interface Builder.   2.) The code I've provided will do what you said and add 50 to the height of the selected row.  However if you keep selecting the row it will add 50 again so you can keep stretching the cell. Probably not what you are going for, you might assign a set value instead of adding 50, or create a way of checking if it's stretched or not before adding 50.

Comment: Also in ViewDidLoad you need to set the delegate.          tableView.delegate = self
        tableView.dataSource = self

Comment: So, 1) I'm sure that it is connected 2) I already keep track of it, and if assign a set value that works perfectly! But if I add anything, nothing happens. Probably something else affacts that, but then why it works for the set value?

Comment: Interesting..  It sounds like no matter what the cell is returning nil.  Let me do some more experimenting to see if I can recreate the problem.

Comment: Oh.  I also have an outlet made and connected for tableView..       @IBOutlet weak var tableView: UITableView!

Comment: So do I, but a strong reference, since I'm using a UITableViewController

Comment: Okay cool, i see.  I started a new TableView project and got my code to work.. so I'm not entirely sure.  I'll have to think about it.   You might need to add override to the functions I included, which you probably already figured out.

Comment: If that can help, a can share the code of my controller, which affects the table

Comment: The only things I didn't mention is I made a custom TableViewController class Swift file, connected the view's Storyboard view to that file in the drop down menu.  I also generated my view's cells with a reuse identifier and a prototype cell.   I'll update the code above with everything in my test.

Comment: yeah that might help.  Sounds like you're doing everything right but it could be something simple.

Comment: [https://drive.google.com/file/d/122HdR7g5YDFgiiIh4SfWY6kdtcm1IS0O/view?usp=sharing] Here's my swift file.

Comment: The real magic behind the code above is the didSet stuff.  So that whenever the variable changes it runs that little update code.  That's what refreshes the height for row..   But I don't really see that in your code. It looks like you're using a IndexPath instead of an Int, so I may need to fiddle with it a bit.

Comment: Maybe something like..      var selectedIndexPath: IndexPath = 999 {
        didSet {
            tableView.beginUpdates()
            tableView.endUpdates()
        }
    }

Comment: So i figured out the solution, though the reason for such a behavior is the thing, I can't understand. My heigthForRowAt function gets called 3 times each time I select or deselect a cell. The first time cellForRow at returns a right cell, but then, it returns nil, for some reason. So I just store the first CGFloat value and then use it for the cell. Though for the general question your answer is right. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

You need to get the cell using `cellForRow` and then get the height of the cell.

```
let cell = tableView.cellForRow(at: indexPath)
let height = cell.bounds.height
```